# concerns about the rules of these sites conflicting with the goals of this particular one

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of 'spoiler' questions on this site.

"Who kills this guy in this film?"

"How many times does this happen in this film? etc etc."

The reason I joined this public beta is because, like many of you, I have a love for movies.

Here is an example question that I would love to ask:

"Who are the cinematographers that you would regard as seminal, and why? and regarding this, what are some classic films that I should watch to see their work?"

Now this question would not be allowed, because it is subjective. However it seems like this would be a GREAT place to ask it. Where else is there such a well structured site with such a great and knowledgeable fan base?

So my question is, will these kinds of questions be allowed? Or is this just going to be a site dedicated to movie trivia?

I'd love to be able to look at questions like this and see a big list of films to watch that people have talked about and decided on. A bit like this question:

http://www.tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks

EDIT - I propose we allow kind of list question on the site. I for one would love to be able to look up a question which tells me what the best anime films to watch if I've never seen any before, or for music, or some quintessential noir films, zombie films, romantic films etc.

I would also add that disallowing subjective answers on a site dedicated to an artform - which is inherently subjective, does not make sense.

The rule for non-subjective questions came from these sites being initially set up for technical topics (like stack overflow) where it is essential to provide factual, canonical answers.

Comment: as a side note, the gaming QandA site is suffering because of this limitation. There someone asked - what are all the known bugs in this game? The question was disallowed because without being a developer of the game, it is theoretically impossible to be aware of all the bugs.

Comment: AND bug listings outdate real quick, AND probably isn't that much of an interesting question anyway. why anyone besides the developer himself (who doesn't know as well) would like a complete assessment of all bugs?

Comment: bugs is my mistake, it was a question about all easter eggs.

Comment: should be interesting to see what happens: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70/who-are-the-most-seminal-cinematographers-in-cinema/77#77

Comment: Relevant chat going on right now http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888

Comment: Please stop downvoting this question. It's a relevant question whether you agree or disagree.

Comment: @SirYakalot votes on meta are historically used differently than votes on the main site. On meta, a downvote means that someone disagrees with you, not that it's a "bad question" or "shows no research". Just fyi.

Comment: I take back what I previously said about subjective questions in general seeing that a lot of film study questions out there will attract subjective questions and I don't think these questions should be off-topic. List questions on the other hand are just difficult to handle. I suggest giving a try to what tex.se did http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls I think I am open to the idea as long as it is manageable

Comment: *"Or is this just going to be a site dedicated to movie trivia?"* - This sounds a bit like the only alternative to such overly broad recommendation list questions would be downright trivial questions. Not sure if I agree with such an overgeneralizing differentiation.

Comment: As a new member, I have already been shot down because a question that was considered 'too broad' was judged exclusively on its *potential* detractions, as opposed to the good answers it was eligible for. I was initally confused, as I assumed that the purpose of the voting system was to downvote bad questions: bizzarely,  everyone agreed it was a **good** question, but was put on hold anyway because it didn't fit the rigid criteria this site enforces. It was incredibly off-putting for a new user...

Comment: @Christian Rau; dont confuse trivia with trivial, thats not the OP's intent.. trivial insinuates of little value or importance.  Trivia is to limit answers to digestible, concise factoids. There are no negative connotations associated to trivia in this context..

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Even in this case I'd still regard most of the `analysis` and `plot-explanation` questions (or most of all the questions on this site) anything else but trivia. For me "trivia" does have a slightly negative connotation (even if different from "trivial") and is not what this site is about, and I dare to say in the OP's context it does come with a negative connotation, too. Trivia is "what was <actor> payed for this role" and not "what is the meaning of <thing> in <movie>".

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional *"It was incredibly off-putting for a new user"* - Yeah, it was hard not to notice how off-putting that was to you. ;-)

Comment: Agreed, but your example of a non-trivia question would likely be down voted or put on hold for being too broad; this is the point the OP is making. Certain users are obsessed with 'objective analysis', two words that are mutually incompatible in most cases. This site is looking for personal knowledge which comes with its bias: better to accept this and let the voting system fulfil its function instead of sanitizing the site with cumbersome rules...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional [No](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14685/49), [it](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14604/49) [wouldn't](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14479/49). We have a multitude of such `analysis` questions. They aren't in any way overly broad. It is true that they can be quite subjective, but if backed by thorough elaborations in questions and answers, this isn't a problem and is an example of *"good subjectivity"* (as SE calls it)...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional ...The problem with the example here for me isn't so much the subjectivity but the broadness. But I'm not too opposed to such questions either, I just didn't like the OP's (what to me seemed) overly narrow view.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional *"Agreed, but your example of a non-trivia question would likely be down voted or put on hold for being too broad"* - You really have given up on this site when that *Breaking Bad* question was killed (and later revived, though) and not bothered to look at any other questions, no?

Comment: @ChristianRau Wow, a direct personal attack from someone who cited me as making things personal previously? An interesting, if not surprising, hypocrisy. I think the fact that my question was revived stands testament to the fact I was right, and you were wrong on that occasion. Now someone has a similar experience, and you're the first to pounce on them? You've made yourself such a permanent feature people haven't noticed you're effectively trolling this site: bleaching it of diversity and scaring off newcomers with your pedantry. The gloves are off.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional *"Wow, a direct personal attack"* - And that *"attack"* was? *"who cited me as making things personal?"* - And that citation was? *"Now someone has a similar experience, and you're the first to pounce on them?"* - And that pounce on his experience was? *"people haven't noticed you're effectively trolling this site: bleaching it of diversity and scaring off newcomers with your pedantry."* - Of course, I'm a pedantic fascist who wants to keep this site down and bothers its users out of bad will. Be it so. My only honest advice left for you is to calm down a little. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau, I assure you I am completely calm, just entirely intolerant of your hypocrisy. Unless these comments get purged (as last time, when *you accused me of making things personal*), people can infer your passive aggressive tone and provocation in your messages. 'out of bad will' - I doubt it's bad will, I bet you don't even realise how oppressive your opinions are. The reason you consider me to have 'given up' is because I don't MSG unless I have something worthwhile to say. Just consider that before you get out your red pen and start marking crosses against new users.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional If you'd like to bury the hatchet and join me in trying to constructively clear any misunderstandings that might have caused your anger on me, I invite you to chat, otherwise I'll stop this discussion for now. Sorry, and please don't let a single evil pedantic troll shatter your believes in this site and your possible future contributions to it. ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11163/discussion-between-christian-rau-and-john-smith-optional)

Answer (score 10):

Why are questions like these not *normally* allowed?

Because it's a pain to clean up when everyone had their fun with it. It's that simple really.

In that C++ question you linked, users are aggressively editing that question. You just don't notice it. Those 41 answers you see might actually be 41 visible answers and 50 deleted ones for all intents and purposes.

Currently there is someone still cleaning up the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books question.

Also that list is not all C++ books, it is the *definite* C++ list. One in which the community agrees on.

Now another user somewhere else already complained about trivia. Since trivia is about basic foundation of movies here then maybe some too basic barrier should be employed to step up the non-trivial nature of questions.

Think about it for a second. It's a Q&A site. You give a question. I give you an objective answer. This is not a discussion forum.

> Who are the cinematographers that you would regard as seminal, and why? and regarding this, what are some classic films that I should watch to see their work?"

With this we can impart Programmers Six principles of subjective

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
- tend to have long, not short, answers.
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
- invite sharing experiences over opinions.
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
- are more than just mindless social fun.

For one your question is way too broad.

> Who are the cinematographers that you would regard as seminal

A. We have moved in one direction here. With n different answers

> and why?

We now have n different variations of each A. type answers

> and regarding this, what are some classic films that I should watch to see their work?

Now we are up another layer to the type of answers that come in.

Is there anything wrong with this? Not really sure, you may need to be checking Literature and Science Fiction sites instead of comparing it to StackOverflow.

You see, this is why we are in private beta so that we can experiment and broaden/tighten the scope to something we can all agree on.

**Convince the community that these type of questions bring across constructive answers and then you got my vote at least.**

How do you do that? *Ask questions on the main site*

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ for more info.

Comment: We all know why there is a rule about subjective questions not being asked. This is a question about whether that rule will limit this site too much.

Comment: Refer to Lit and Science Fiction sites to see how it was dealt with there. Seeing that these sites are non-technical it would be best to see what happened there. Don't assume every person knows why subjective questions are frowned upon also. @sir

Comment: @SirYakalot see also this previous discussion http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1/dealing-with-recommendation-questions

Answer (score 3):

The question, as currently stated, is **way** too broad, it's the same equivalent of asking who the most influential book authors are and what should I read to get a good sample of their work?  I could see this working, maybe, on literature if it was written “Who are the most influential sci-fi authors and what works highlight this influence?”

Answer (score 2):

I think those question are very interesting and get some great discussions. I would also like to ask people for recommendations, but at the end of the day this is a question and answer site and those answers are too subjective and are better suited to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a movie forum.

Also, you can't really accept an answer that is always true. Maybe you accept Fred's answer of 3 movies but then the next month I come back with a list that totally blows Fred's out of the water.

Comment: sure but if we disallow these kinds of questions, I for one will not be interested in being a member of this site. It's the collective knowledge of people that interests me - people's ability to turn me on to things that I haven't seen or heard about.